# How to create an instance of Polymer element programmatically?

Tags: polymer

Please refer to this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cijerineva/1/edit?html,output), basically I would like to create an instance of an element in its parent element scope. Wondering how should I do this?

If possible, is there a declarative way to do this?

Thanks.

PS. Please open the link in Chrome only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the `constructor` (see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html)) attribute.

You need to include it in your polymer element declaration.

```
<polymer-element name="p-paper" 
                 attributes="content" 
                 constructor="Paper"
                 noscript>
```

And then you can create instances of your element like this -

```
  // How to create an instance of <p-paper> here?  
  var paper = new Paper();
```

Comment: Thanks, that is the answer, but another problem comes, which is the actual problem. `new Paper()` gives me an DOM node, how can I pass the data to a DOM node? I found one way to do this, please see this JSBin, http://jsbin.com/rowejugeve/4/ This makes me feel that the model and the DOM is not bound together...

Comment: I wonder if the answers in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27827927/how-to-bind-polymer-custom-element-to-the-contents/27831165#27831165) would help?

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to instantiate and element.

Declarative:

```
<my-element>
```

JS:

```
document.createElement('my-element');
```

Constructor (if one is find):

```
new MyElement();
```

See http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/#instantiating